# Google Ad Manager - Why order lines do not appear in ad blocks?

Tags: google-ad-manager

The order lines that I have assigned in an ad block do not appear in the ad block

This is the order line and it says it is in the ad block "Horizontal Banner Top 3".
[Horizontal banner top3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsrvW.png)

But when I go to the ad block, I don't see it
[Ad Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKnhV.png)

What could be going on?

I was creating new order lines, creating new ad blocks and none of this worked.

I was checking the ad manager limits and it doesn't even come close to exceeding them.